# Why localhost React application different compared with production version hosted on CloudFront?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cloudfront

I have a React application deployed on CloudFront. Today after checking functionalities on my application, I saw some different compare with localhost.

For example:

```
Localhost:  Displayed a loading after submitting form
Production: Loading don't display after form submitted
```

I think can missing a js or css resources.
The problem is just happening today, before is not.

Thanks in advance!